# save to localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm curious if its possible to save the text input a user types in the field to localStorage , so in this html example , i'd want to save the innner html from the div#match_player_id , that is created when you click the button

```
<input type="text" id="contract_year" placeholder="Contract" autocomplete="off">

<input value="Submit" onclick="document.querySelector('#match_player_id').innerHTML = document.querySelector('#contract_year').value" type="button">

<div id="match_player_id"></div>
```

Comment: Have a look at some more generic JavaScript tutorials. While what you ask for is possible, your approach is only glancing the surface of what needs to be done. Specifically, if you are working with jQuery, look at the `.on("click", ...)` functionality along with the `$(selector)` syntax.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to use a javascript function instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateMatchPlayerId() {
    var matchPlayerId = document.querySelector('#contract_year').value;
    document.querySelector('#match_player_id').innerHTML =  matchPlayerId;
    if (typeof Storage !== "undefined") {
        localStorage.setItem("matchPlayerId", matchPlayerId);
    }
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="contract_year" placeholder="Contract" autocomplete="off">

<input value="Submit" onclick="updateMatchPlayerId()" type="button">

<div id="match_player_id"></div>
```

Comment: ok i tested and i see it is storing the content of #match_player_id , but on refresh its not re displaying it

Comment: In your question you only talk about to "save" a value in local storage. Anyway, you can use `localStorage.getItem("matchPlayerId")` to retrieved the previously saved value.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should really be using unobtrusive event handlers to hook to events instead of the outdated `on*` event attributes. As you've tagged jQuery in the question this can be done incredibly simply.

From there you can just use `localStorage.setItem()` to save the value you require, like this:

```js
$('button').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var contractYear = $('#contract_year').val();
  $('#match_player_id').html(contractYear);

  localStorage.setItem(contractYear);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="contract_year" placeholder="Contract" autocomplete="off">
<button type="button">Submit</button>
<div id="match_player_id"></div>
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lm3jss6/)