# How to save data externally in HTML when refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am new to javascript so i dont have that much idea which is the best way.

THis is my HTML code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
<title>System Links</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="graphics.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Brain.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="hello">Test-Page-Production</h1>
<div id="button2" ><a href="FrontPage.html">Production</a></div>
<div id="button2"><a href="SecondPage.html">NonProduction</a></div>


<table id= "Hello" style="height:;width:100%; position: absolute; top: 200px; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;border:1px solid" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>CheckBox</th>
    <th>Host</th>
    <th>SID</th>
    <th>NR</th>
    <th>SCS</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>URL</th>
    <th>SAP Components</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr >
    <td><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></td>
    <td>Host Name</td>
    <td>SID</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>ABAP</td>
    <td><a href="https://www.facebook.com/">Links</a></td>
    <td>HanaSystem</td></tr>

    <tr>
    <td><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></td>
    <td>Host Name</td>
    <td>SID</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>ABAP</td>
    <td>Links</td>
    <td>HanaSystem</td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
    <td><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></td>
    <td>Host Name</td>
    <td>SID</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>ABAP</td>
    <td>Links</td>
    <td>HanaSystem</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="add" onClick="addRow()">
Add Row</button>


<button id="delete" onClick="deleteCell()">
Delete Row</button>

</body>
</html>


This is my javascript code:

function addRow()
{

var Host=prompt("Enter Host Name");  
var SID=prompt("Enter System ID"); 
var NR=prompt("Enter the NRsd:");
var SystemNumber=prompt("Enter System Number"); 
var Type=prompt("Enter the Type"); 
var URL=prompt("Enter the URL"); 
var SystemComponents=prompt("Enter the System Components");

               //tableBody=document.getElementsByTagName("tbody").item(0);
               var tableBody = document.getElementById('Hello').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
               //row=document.createElement("tr");   
               var row   = tableBody.insertRow(tableBody.rows.length);


               var newCell0 =row.insertCell(0);
               var cb = document.createElement('input');
               var cb=document.createElement('input');
               cb.type = 'checkbox';
               newCell0.appendChild(cb);


               // Insert a cell in the row at index 0
               var newCell  = row.insertCell(1);
               // Append a text node to the cell
               var newText  = document.createTextNode(Host);
               newCell.appendChild(newText);


               // Insert a cell in the row at index 0
               var newCell1  = row.insertCell(2);
               // Append a text node to the cell
               var newText1  = document.createTextNode(SID);
               newCell1.appendChild(newText1);



               // Insert a cell in the row at index 0
               var newCell2  = row.insertCell(3);
               // Append a text node to the cell
               var newText2  = document.createTextNode(NR);
               newCell2.appendChild(newText2);




               // Insert a cell in the row at index 0
               var newCell3  = row.insertCell(4);
               // Append a text node to the cell
               var newText3  = document.createTextNode(SystemNumber);
               newCell3.appendChild(newText3);



               // Insert a cell in the row at index 0
               var newCell4  = row.insertCell(5);
               // Append a text node to the cell
               var newText4  = document.createTextNode(Type);
               newCell4.appendChild(newText4);



               // Insert a cell in the row at index 0
               var newCell5 = row.insertCell(6);
               // Append a text node to the cell
               var newText5  = document.createTextNode(URL);
               newCell5.appendChild(newText5);


               // Insert a cell in the row at index 0
               var newCell6= row.insertCell(7);
               // Append a text node to the cell
               var newText6  = document.createTextNode(SystemComponents);
               newCell6.appendChild(newText6);

}

function deleteCell(){


//var tableBody = document.getElementById('Hello').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
//document.getElementById('Hello').getElementsByTagName('tbody').deleteRow(4);

 //var confirmation=window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete");

var tableBody = document.getElementById('Hello').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
var confirmation=window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete");
var rowCount = tableBody.rows.length;
if(confirmation==true){
for(var i=0;i<rowCount;i++){
    var row = tableBody.rows[i];
    var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
    if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                    tableBody.deleteRow(i);
                    rowCount--;
                    i--;
                }
}
}


}
```

Whenever the user presses the addrow button data should get saved.So how to achieve this in the most precise way.Since in my case whenver user clicks on refresh button the page again refreshes from start without saving any data.

Comment: Html is on client side. Whenever you refresh page your server would return same unchanged data. You need to send request to server and save changes there.

Comment: Your question is 'To save data externally' so you must know that you cannot have persistent data in the clients HTML page. Are you wanting advice on how to store it externally? If so, the question will probably be closed as too broad. Could you provide more information about what server side technology you are using (if any)?

Comment: Use javascript ajax to send the 'json' data to the server (back-end code) and persist your data there. You can have a postback to check or load the new data and update your HTML markup accordingly.

Comment: Can be duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408340/how-do-i-save-the-markup-change-i-made-when-going-from-one-page-to-the-next/43408428#43408428

Comment: Possible duplicate of [save to localStorage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43129215/save-to-localstorage)

Comment: @IvanIvanov so which server side language should i use to save the data in the server?

Comment: @SeanOB yes i want your advice on how to store it externally?

Comment: @ThatAwesomeCoder can you give me a example how to dynamically save the data in the server side in the table.

Comment: @RaviUbana local storage only solve half of the problem i guess.

Comment: @RaviUbana using cookies also i dont think the problem would be solved

Comment: @NiladriChanda There is a plethora of server languages. I suppose, that easiest to install and use are nodejs or golang, but it depends. Also, you need a database to store data. Please, provide usecase of your "application", maybe there IS a way to avoid server side.

Comment: Its not at all completed here only the client updates the system name,system number and url .Since there are more then 150 system and different system have different URL,so i want this job  done by the different client.  In short its a kind of dynamic page where different URL is maintained so that client dont have to search seperately for the URLs @IvanIvanov

Comment: This is not a client job. Everything needs to be synchronized on server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data in the browser's localStorage or sessionStorage.

1) After click the Add button, then save date the localStorage/sessionStorage.
2) After page reload, retrieve the data from localStorage/sessionStorage and populate the tables by javascript.

To save a item:
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

To retrieve a item 
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');

The API Reference is here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: The question i have if i use local storage then whether every client can dynamically add data or not and  for each client  whether the data will be shown that is added by other client?

Comment: Yes every client can dynamically add data. But each client will only see their own data (because it's stored locally by their own browser).

Comment: But i need the full flexibility so that each  client can see the data what other client have added.So is there any way to do that?

Comment: Yes, but not using this method suggested. You need a server side web framework. From here you need to do the research, pick something, and have a go. There are many factors to consider. Read this for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/First_steps/Web_frameworks#How_to_select_a_web_framework